# Spring Boot + angular routeProvider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring-boot

I want to create project with using Spring boot + rest + angularJS, I did whole back end with rest, I'm using angular first time and I watched a lot of tutorials for creating UI, so, I did all as in many tutorials but anyway it doesnt work and I cannot understand why because event doesnt exist an error I'm sitting 2 days for solving problem and I'm crushed. I don't know what to do. Please, someone help me to set up routeProvider correct, I downloaded whole angular libs and put in project. So, take a look please.

My app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']).

    config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when("/books/", {templateUrl:"/templates/book/list.html"})
}
);
```

My book.html, I did img because I want you see that tag  isn't readable:

[book.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MRc9.png)

and list.html:

[list.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeaA4.png)

And when I go to localhost:8080/books/ it gives me Json value from RestController and no any error like 404 or anything.

[image]

Comment: You're supposed to include all the relevant information directly in the question, not via screenshots/links.

Comment: I've sent in this way because I wanted you look at the <data-ng-view> tag that html doesnt see it, that's why.

Comment: One suggestion I would make would not to use the minified version of any script during development. These versions are don't usually give very helpful error message. Instead download the normal versions and import them. For example, http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angular-1.4.4/angular.js.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a controller for each view. Add this:

```
$routeProvider.when(
          "/books/",
           controller: 'YourBooksController',
           {templateUrl:"/templates/book/list.html"}
   )
```

However i strongly suggest you to use [ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: No, it didn't help me. I saw many times that it works even without controller but in my situation very huge thing goes wrong and I cannot understand what exactly, I'm trying second day already =(

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Boot + AngularJS documentation is pretty good: [Spring and Angular JS: A Secure Single Page Application](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js). This tutorial includes a simple router that you can use as an example for resolving your issues.

For full featured application example code try [JHipster](http://jhipster.github.io/).